# Pop Up Window while service is running in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service

Can anyone tell me how can i pop up a window while service is running in android, means, i am developing an app which will pop a window when incoming call is detected in android phone. I have searched a lot but not found any exact explanation. So please tell me how can i do this.

And I am using this code. When i run this app it quit forcibly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class CallHelper extends Activity
{


    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
     */
    public class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {


        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Out.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   //must be provided
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */


    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;



    public CallHelper(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;     
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();

    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() 
    {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() 
    {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

    }
       //Intent intent = new Intent(); 
       //startService(intent);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the Broadcast receiver in your  service in manifest.xml
---------------------------------------------   
<receiver android:name="com.pericent.saferide.recciver.InComingCall" >
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
--------------------------------------------------
and when call is coming you call your activity in on receive method  of BroadcastReciver

and you change your code listener like this
-------------------------------------------------- 
switch(state) {
            case CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                checkCallAsUnreceived(incomingNumber);
                break;
            case CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:    //call was received
                checkCallAsReceived();
                break;
            case CALL_STATE_IDLE:       //no active calls
                sendMsgIfCallWasntReceived();
                break;
        }
-------------------------------------------------------------

and for more detail you can see the below url:-
https://github.com/MarcinOS/AutoResponder
```